# Is there any way to condense my code so it does not take up so many lines?

Tags: python, function

I'm writing my program in python and have it working properly, but it's over 500 lines of code. I think there is a way I can condense my code, but I'm not sure how I should do it

Here's an example of some of my code:

```
def click():
    if clicked1.get() == "app1":
        os.startfile(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\app1")
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=".*app1")
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
    if clicked1.get() == "app2":
        os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\app2")
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=".*app2")
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
```

I basically have about 20 of those if statements for each different
application and for each different clicked (1-4). Is there any way I can shrink my code so it doesn't take up so many lines? Perhaps using variables?

Comment: Write a function? or a loop?

Comment: half of it is repaeted, you could use a string variable for the input parameter of  `os.startfile` and only use the If estatement for that, the rest should be written only once.

Comment: If your code is working, but you want open-ended advice on improving and streamlining it, your question would be a much better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a data driven approach that lets you add apps to the map at the top of the code, and also makes it easy for you to add additional per-app quantities to each of the map entries:

```
apps = {
    "app1": {
        "startfile": r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\app1",
        "title_re": ".*app1"
    },
    "app2": {
        "startfile": r"C:\Program Files (x86)\app2",
        "title_re": ".*app2"
    }
}

def click():
    if clicked1.get() in apps:
        app = apps[clicked1.get()]
        os.startfile(app["startfile"])
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=app["title_re"])
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Prbably something like this, where the only comparisson made is to generate  astring for the input parameter of `os.startfile`.

Half of the code was unneesarily repeated

```
def click():
    ruturnstr = ""
    appstr = ""
    if clicked1.get() == "app1":
        ruturnstr = "C:\Users\red\Desktop\app1"
        appstr = ".*app1"
    else:
        ruturnstr = "C:\Program Files (x86)\app2"
        appstr = ".*app2"

    os.startfile(ruturnstr )
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        try:
            app.connect(title_re=appstr )
            break
        except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
    app1 = app.top_window()
    app1.move_window(x1, y1)
    time.sleep(.5)
    app1.maximize()
```

Comment: You missed that `title_re` also changes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can extract out the clicked value and the startfile

```
def foo(name, location):
    if clicked1.get() == name:
        os.startfile(location)
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=".*" + name)
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
```

Then you can loop over a tuple of name/location pairs